# Module not found while creating build for ios ? Flutter

Tags: swift, flutter

I have completed flutter projects.  and now i am trying to create builds for Android and iOS . but while creating builds for Ios i get this error

> Module not found.

What is the issue,

```
#if __has_include(<admob_flutter/AdmobFlutterPlugin.h>)
#import <admob_flutter/AdmobFlutterPlugin.h>
#else
@import admob_flutter;
#endif
```

Comment: did you installed and updated pods?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have install pods.

Go to IOS Folder

```
pod deintegrate

pod install
```

If It's not working then check which Minimum IOS version required by Package.

Also make sure that you have opened the Runner.xcworkspace file in XCode, not the Runner.xcodeproj file